# how do to Xb calculation in R2OpenBUGS, when p is not known

Tags: openbugs

I want to calculate x1b1+x2b2+......+xpbp. However, p is not known, I cannot write it down in advance. So I want to do the following. But in BUGS it says multiple definitions error.

```
  betax <- 0
  for(k in 1:p){
    betax <- betax + beta[k]*x[i,k]
  }
```

Is there any ways to get it done in bugs model?

Comment: The error is because you defined betax several times in the loop (from what I read in a google.)

Comment: THX, I got it fixed